# Running Terraform on Azure Container Instances (ACI)

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-container-instances

I am trying to run some terraform code an Azure Container Instances. But I can't get it to actually start the container.

I am running it from cli, using a yml file. There is a main.tf with an hello world config

This is the yml

```
apiVersion: '2019-12-01'

location: ukwest
name: file-share-demo
properties:
  containers:
  - name: hellofiles
    properties:
      environmentVariables: []
      command: [
        terraform -chdir=/data/terraform/hello/ apply --auto-approve
      ]
      image: hashicorp/terraform
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1.0
          memoryInGB: 1.5
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /data
        name: filesharevolume
  osType: Linux
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
  - name: filesharevolume
    azureFile:
      sharename: scripts
      storageAccountName: 'name'
      storageAccountKey: 'key'
tags: {}
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

I passed all kinds of commands but I can't get it to launch...

Comment: As per documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-start-command#examples), it looks like `"command": ["python", "myscript.py", "arg1", "arg2"]` with `template`

Comment: @harshavmb yeah that doesn't work, it just gives the raw /bin/terraform output - maybe its something to do with the terraform container itself. but I couldn't make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

The command needed to get this working is

```
["/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/terraform -chdir=/apps apply --auto-approve"]
```

if you try to make it into separate command options then it only runs the terraform part. I've no clue why, but that works!